# Here-API What's the difference between NavigationManager.PositionListener and PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener

Tags: android, here-api

I'm trying to use the Android here-sdk for some simple navigation app.

At the moment I'm adding a NavigationManager.PositionListener to the NavigationManager and a PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener to my positioningManager... Is there a reason to have both? Do I actually need both?

Thanks,
j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only `PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener` is sufficient. Using `NavigationManager.PositionListener` will simply return the same information as `PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener` but only while navigating.